# ejs.renderFile result convert to string

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ejs, sendgrid

Good day, i need to convert **ejs.renderfile result** to **string** for subsequent sending by mail through the "SendGrid" service

```
const emailTemplatCompany = ejs.renderFile(// options)
```

There is something like this in **emailTemplatCompany** variable:

```
Promise {
  '<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n' +
    '<html lang="en">\r\n' +
    '<head>\r\n' +
    '    <meta charset="UTF-8">\r\n' +
    '    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">\r\n' +
    '    <style>\r\n' +
    '        body{\r\n' ........
}
```

Can you help find the best answer for solving this problem

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try `emailTemplatCompany.then(str => console.log(str))` By looking at the documentation you could also do `ejs.renderFile(filename, data, options, function(err, str){  // str => Rendered HTML string });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `ejs.render` or `ejs.renderFile` to do this. The difference between those two methods is that `render()` requires a template-string as input and is synchronous:

```
const resolvedTemplateAsStr = ejs.render(str, data);
```

`renderFile()` requires a path to the template file as input and is async:

```
const resolvedTemplateAsStr = await ejs.renderFile('./path/to/template.ejs', data);
```